# Translation for Non-Components. (I have already looked at Intl)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, internationalization

Does app fabric have something that supports translation of data directly (NOTE: I don't want React's Intl since that is meant for localising data before it is rendered). I need to localise the data present in the state and update the state with the translated data.

React's intl is intended to be used with components and I require translation of data present outside components. I don't want to use the createIntl module since that requires manual provision of locale & messages.

This is the code that I'm dealing with. It is present outside a component.

```
export function func () {
   client.get (url, {}).then (
      response => {
          // handle error
    }).then(data => {
        // This is where i want to translate the data based on the locale i am in
        // so that the data this translated data is present in the state
      }
// error-handling, more code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/overview/getting-started) to translate data in plain js.

Basic Example:

```js
import i18next from 'i18next';
i18next.init({
  lng: 'en', // if you're using a language detector, do not define the lng option
  debug: true,
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: {
        "key": "hello world"
      }
    }
  }
});
// initialized and ready to go!
// i18next is already initialized, because the translation resources where passed via init function
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = i18next.t('key');
```

By the way, why not translate data on the server-side? You may encounter some cases like `export excel` which may require translation, too.